# How to get a specif data from firebase realtime database api in reactjs using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get a specific user based upon its mail and password which I have stored in the firebase, I am learning reactJs & using axios to make a request to get data from firebase using an API "https://hotel-reservation-77656.firebaseio.com/registration.json" but the problem is as with GET request it fetches all the data from the database

I tried passing different query params in url of the browser

```
 const signUp = {
                    mail: "john",
                    pass: "passwor",

                }
                axios.get('registration').then(res => {
                    alert("Login Successfull");
                    console.log(res)

                }).catch(error => {
                    alert("Error Occured!!!"+error)
                })
```

Comment: You don't know how did they implement their api, so i think it'll be better if you use the official [SDK library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) to communicate with firebase real time database

Comment: You can filter the data by *either* mail *or* password as shown in the documentation on [filtering data with the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering). You can't filter on both though, as Firebase only allows filtering on a single property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase